# Play animated gif on event in react web app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, animated-gif

I'm trying to play an animated gif on a mousedown event in a React app, at the position of the cursor, then make it disappear.
The problem is that the gif doesn't always play, it just gets stuck at the first frame.

I've tried it using the useState hook, setting it to visible then with the setTimeout clearing it after the gif played.

code summary:

```
const [sparking, setSparking] = useState(false);

function sparkNow(e) {
    setSparking(cursorCoordinates);
    setTimeout(() => {
       setSparking(false);
    }, 600);
}

return(
    {sparking && (<img ... />)}
}
```

How do I make this work?
Maybe it has to do with the gif I've made, its available in the in the example below

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-browser-gjrt2q?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, instead of conditionally rendering the whole img tag, I just changed the src to a state value (which I clear when after the GIF played) and toggle the visibility to hidden.

```
<img
    src={sparking.src}
    style={{ visibility: `${sparking? "visible" : "hidden"}` }}
/>
```

event handler function:

```
setSparking({src: "./images/spark.gif"});
setTimeout(() => {
    setSparking(false);
}, 600);
```